# Orienatation Animation not showing when orientation will change ios Swift

Tags: ios, swift

i am having some code in Appdelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions Method which show different ViewController according to code. after adding this code animation not showing when orientation will change.But if i remove this code then animation showing.can someone explain me how to fix this?and this is the code.

```
       self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var vc:UIViewController

    if (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Person") as? Bool) == nil {

        vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstNavigationView")

    }else{

        vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainView")

    }

    self.window?.rootViewController = vc
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: Can you let me how you are setting RootviewController before this changes and  You are not using any NavigationController for the Setting the rootviewController in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code in your view controller and give a try

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil, completion: {
        _ in
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    })
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
}
```